# NSString compare:options:range: - which value to pass for no options?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to call [NSString compare:options:range:] and pass no options.

What should be the correct value to provide for the options parameter?

Both nil and NULL produce a warning in Xcode : "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to parameter of type ... "

Comment: without options, you don't need to do this at all.

Comment: not really - I do want to provide a value for the range parameter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just pass `0`. Alternatively, if you've been around the Mac block a few times, you might catch yourself passing `kNilOptions` which is just another name for `0`, but implies the relevant flagginess.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't run across that one before. Looks like it's intended to be used with `OptionBits` arguments, which of course is a type nobody uses anymore.

Comment: Again, around the block a few times. ;p

Comment: I think this constant is named in a way that it just says anything about the value I want to pass - I like it very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `0`. The `options` argument is a bit mask, which really means it's just an integer. That's also why the warning says "integer conversion".

Comment: yeah - that makes sense ... I was just fixated on a fading memory that in the past I was putting NULL in there

Comment: If you command-click the method to go to its declaration, and then command-click the type of the `options` argument, you'll see it's usually just a typedef of `NSUInteger`

Answer (score -1):

As Apple Docs says:

> Options for the search—you can combine any of the following using a C bitwise OR operator: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch, NSLiteralSearch, NSNumericSearch.
>   See String Programming Guide for details on these options.

`NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` : A case-insensitive search.

`NSLiteralSearch` : Exact character-by-character equivalence.

`NSNumericSearch` : Numbers within strings are compared using numeric value, that is, Name2.txt < Name7.txt < Name25.txt.

[String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i)

Comment: this does not answer my question, of course I first checked the docs

Comment: And why you didn't pass one of this parameters?

Comment: @Nekto: You may want to re-read the OP's question. He doesn't want any of the parameters. He wanted to know what to pass to indicate an absence of parameters.

Comment: The correct value is to use one of predefined constants because when Apple will redefined them to another values he will caught a bug.